# Flutter change notifier provider updating data

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I want to know what is the correct way to update the data in Flutter using the Change Notifier Provider.

I have the following provider used to get recipes and also add recipes to a firestore database.

```
import 'package:fit_track/models/recipe/recipe_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import '../services/recipe_service.dart';

class RecipeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late RecipeService _recipeService;
  List<RecipeModel> recipes = [];
  List<RecipeModel> otherRecipes = [];
  late Future getUserRecipesFuture;
  late Future getOtherRecipesFuture;
  String? _filter;

  RecipeProvider() {
    _recipeService = RecipeService();
    getUserRecipesFuture = _getUserRecipesFuture();
    getOtherRecipesFuture = _getOtherRecipesFuture();
  }

  Future _getUserRecipesFuture() async {
    recipes = await _recipeService.getUserRecipes();
  }

  Future _getOtherRecipesFuture() async {
    otherRecipes = await _recipeService.getOtherRecipes();
  }

  Future addImage(String recipeName, XFile? image) async {
    try {
      String imageUrl = await _recipeService.addImage(recipeName, image);

      return imageUrl;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }

  Future addRecipe(RecipeModel newRecipe) async {
    try {
      await _recipeService.addRecipe(newRecipe, recipes.length + 1);

      recipes = await _recipeService.getUserRecipes();
      //recipes.add(newRecipe);

      notifyListeners();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
}
```

My question is which is the correct way to update the list of recipes for the user. In the addRecipe method I called the services in order to retrieve the new list of recipes, including the added one. Under it I commented the line which just adds the new recipe to the list, without calling the services.
Which of these options is the correct one? And if neither are how should it be done?

Comment: I don't think it's a question of one or the other being "correct". They both work, and have slightly different meaning. Getting the list from your service means that any business logic the service might have will be applied (imagine converting from imperial to metric units, as an example).